# Conversion to char but complet with blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT 
 ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR(8), A.field1), REPLICATE(' ', 8)) + 
 ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR(10), A.field2), REPLICATE(' ', 10)) 
from #tmpTable a
```

I have to concat some field. Field1 and Field2 are integer, when I convert to char, they must have
a specific size. If the value of field1 is 123 the result must be '123     ' (with the blank).

At the end I want something like this :

```
123        456
985454     232355
```

If the value is null, I have an empty space of 8 or 10 blank

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Update1:
The result I need is

```
         1001335
         1001335
12401886 10994
```

[image]

Comment: The plus sign in the 2nd row seems to be wrong

Comment: yes removed but it's not the problem

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `REPLICATE` when you convert the integer to `char(8)` it will automatically have a length of 8 characters.

```
      Select Convert(Char(8), IsNull(a.Field1,'')) + 
           Convert(Char(10), IsNull(a.Field2,''))
    From #tmpTable
```

**UPDATE**

Apologies, you need to convert to `char` before the `IsNull` otherwise it will be a zero.

Like this:

```
Create Table #t
(
Field1 int,
Field2 int
)
Insert Into #t
Select Null, 1001335
union all
select Null, 1001335
union all
select 1445121, 1001335
union all
select 1331445, null


Select IsNull(Convert(Char(8), a.Field1),'') + 
       IsNull(Convert(Char(10), a.Field2),'')
From #t a

Drop table #t
```

Comment: Sorry I do not find the query which produces 0